# ag grid cellStyle not assignable to type in v30.x

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

Below code is having no compilation error when using ag-grid-enterprise:25.3.0

```
columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {  field: 'select',maxWidth: 40,pinned: 'left', lockPinned: true, headerCheckboxSelection:  params =>   {return this.isProdUser ? false : true},  checkboxSelection: true, cellStyle: params => {return this.isProdUser ? {'pointer-events': 'none', opacity: '0.4' } : '';}},
    { headerName: 'Actions', field: 'id', suppressMenu: true,pinned: 'left',lockPinned: true, cellRendererFramework: ImgDeleterenderer, cellRendererParams: { context: this },width: 66 },    
    { headerName: 'Report Title', field: 'title', tooltipField: 'title',tooltipComponentFramework: ObjectiveTooltipComponent,sortable: true, width: 125,filter: true },
    ];
```

And after i upgraded it to latest version 30.1.0, i am getting below errors. I dont find any documentation explaining what is replaced.

```
[{
    "resource": "setup-report.component.ts",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2322",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Type '(params: CellClassParams<any, any>) => \"\" | { 'pointer-events': string; opacity: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CellStyle | CellStyleFunc<any, any>'.\n  Type '(params: CellClassParams<any, any>) => \"\" | { 'pointer-events': string; opacity: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CellStyleFunc<any, any>'.\n    Type '\"\" | { 'pointer-events': string; opacity: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CellStyle'.\n      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'CellStyle'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 48,
    "startColumn": 176,
    "endLineNumber": 48,
    "endColumn": 185,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 315,
            "startColumn": 5,
            "endLineNumber": 315,
            "endColumn": 14,
            "message": "The expected type comes from property 'cellStyle' which is declared here on type 'ColDef<any, any>'",
            "resource": "/node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/entities/colDef.d.ts"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: It was renamed: https://www.ag-grid.com/changelog/?fixVersion=30.0.0

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks i found replacement for tooltipComponentFramework and cellRendererFramework. But the cellstyle issue i could not find anything

Comment: You're returning a value of an invalid type. See the requirements of the [`cellStyle`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-styles/#cell-style) function. Basically you can't return a `string` so `this.isProdUser ? {'pointer-events': 'none', opacity: '0.4' } : undefined;}` is what you want because you have to return either an object or `null` or `undefined`.